# android - email not working in samsung galaxy s

Tags: android

I want to open android default email client directly. It's working in most of the devices except "Samsung Galaxy S". Actually the problem is i set the subject and body of the email in the coding this was effected in the most of the devices but it's not effected in samsung galaxy s. Here an empty compose mail opened.  what can I do to make it work?

**Code**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
            emailIntent.setType("text/html");
            List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0);
            if (!resInfo.isEmpty())
            {
                for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) 
                {
                    System.out.println("info.activityInfo.packageName:"+info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase());
                    System.out.println("info.activityInfo.name:"+info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase());
                    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains("mail") || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("mail")) 
                    {
                        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Allergy Journal");       
                        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My Allergy Journal Body");                                 
                        emailIntent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);   
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));   
                    }
                } 
            }

    }});
```

Comment: while setting subject and body of the mail,you have checked two conditions of: packageName and name while inside it you are setting package as packagename.the prob might be there, it must be satisfying name condition but getting setPackage line it wont be showing you the subject and body.

Comment: I have pasted your code. and its working perfectly fine.. are getting any error?

Comment: It's working fine but it's not working in samsung galaxy S. I don't have that device i sent the apk file to my friend he told that issue. are You having samsung galaxy s device now?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    Intent email=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "YOUR SUBJECT");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"YOUR MESSAGE BODY");
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    a.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email Client :"));
```